# Ethernet over Powerline working between apartments. Should I be worried?

Tags: power-line-communication

We have two different apartments, side by side (same floor), with separate electrical panels. For some reason Powerline can transfer Ethernet between the two apartments (with a bit under 60Mbps bandwidth!). Some times the Powerline adapters may need to resync or just stop working, but that happens very rarely (~2 times a year).

Should I be worried that the two apartments are sharing wiring or that their panels are not separating them properly?

Comment: @King: I think we're talking about Ethernet over mains wiring with one device in each apartment. I suspect that *powerline* is a brand name and should be capitalised.

Comment: @Transistor yes you are correct (it was capitalized in the title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be worried that the two apartments are sharing wiring or that their panels are not separating them properly?

Of course not. You're sharing the same supply with half the street. Everyone on your transformer will share the supply. If it is a three-phase supply then it is likely that 1/3 of the users will be on each phase. It's quite likely that your whole building is on the same supply.

If you were not on the same supply you would not be able to transmit data between apartments using the mains wiring.

Comment: One third of the users would not be on the same phase, apartment buildings are going to have two or three phases delivered to them depending on how large they are, even a small home would have two phases.

Comment: @Matt, that depends on the location. In Ireland and UK domestic installations are single-phase 230 V. Individual apartment would be single-phase.

Comment: This is an American website, not a British one. Those claims are irrelevant.

Comment: No, @Matt, it's an English language, international website. There is no user location in the original question and SE seems to have removed the user location from the profiles pages.

Comment: Again, no, its American. Stack Exchange Inc.
110 William Street
28th Floor
New York, NY 10038

Comment: @Matt, I'm not sure what point you are trying to make. Sure, the site is owned by an American company but it has a worldwide userbase and many of the top contributers are European. We don't only answer questions about America! Location specific questions should give the location information.

Comment: Just as the default language here is English the default locality is the USA as this is an American website. If you want to talk about some small and largely irrelevant country like Ireland then you can certainly specify that, but any question is implied to be relevant to the US unless otherwise specified. Just as you're going to look foolish if you start answering questions in Irish.